# Weird positioning of flash object in Chrome

Tags: html, css

This link displays properly in firefox, but the flash youtube player loads way down the page in chrome. What am I doing wrong? 
http://www.computerlabsolutions.com/success/video_testimonials_test.cfm

Answer (score 0):

In chrome right click the place where the flash should be and click "inspect element",it will show you all the css properties of that object,just change the values and try.

Answer (score 0):

The width of the object is wider than its containing `div`.  Try changing the object's width to be 650px like the div, or change the container.